# Using Testcafe Selectors: withText then sibling

Tags: testing, filter, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to create a selector using the `withText` filter and wanting to select the sibling element.

given: `const Create_asset = S('span').withText('Create Asset')`

`Create_asset()` returns a `ReExecutablePromise` with the `nextSibling()` method.
`await Create_asset()` returns a DOM-like(?) object, but without the `nextSibling()` method, so it seems I can't do `await Create_asset().withText('text').nextSibling()`

How can I select a sibling subsequently when using the `withText()` filter?

Thanks for any debugging tips too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below returns a [DOM Node Snapshot](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#dom-node-snapshot).

```
const mySelector = Selector('span').withText('text');
const snapshot   = await mySelector();
```

In your test scenario you can do something like this:

```
await t

    .expect(mySelector.withText('some text').nextSibling().getAttribute('id')).eql('id1');
```

Note: [TestCafe allows you to debug server-side test code and test behavior on the client](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/debugging.html)